# Validate Upload files based on its content

Tags: django

I was trying to verify uploading file. First I tried to check the extension. 
but if malicious file with a following extension will also be passed the check.

```
def validate_file_extension(value):
    ext = os.path.splitext(value.name)[1]
    valid_extensions = ['.pdf', '.doc', '.docx', '.jpg', '.png', '.xlsx', '.xls', 'ppt']
    if not ext.lower() in valid_extensions:
        raise ValidationError(u'Unsupported file extension.')
```

Then I tried to use python magic, this would looks in to the file and decide the actual type.

```
def validate_file_type(value):
    file_type = magic.from_buffer(value.read(1024), mime=True)

    valid_file_types = ['image/png',
                        'image/jpg','text/plain',
                        'application/pdf',
                        'application/ms-excel',]
    if not file_type.lower() in valid_file_types:
        raise ValidationError(u'Unsupported file.')
```

But Excel, Word, and ppt files are recognized as 'application/zip'. So cannot use this approach for MS documents.
Is there any better way to validate upload files?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here.
https://pypi.org/project/django-constrainedfilefield/

Just have to use `ConstrainedFileField` instead of `FileField`.
That validates even the file extension changed.

```
attach_file = ConstrainedFileField(
                                    null=True,
                                    blank=True,
                                    upload_to='directory_path',
                                    content_types=contents,
                                    max_upload_size=1024000
                                            )
```